# Determine which vector is closer to a plane by looking at projections.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, projection

Suppose we are given a plane in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ with its scalar equation, we are also given two vectors $\vec{x},\vec{y}$, is it possible to determine which of $\vec{x},\vec{y}$ is closer to the plane $P$ by only calculating $proj_{P}\vec{x}$ and $proj_{P}\vec{y}$?

Edit: To be clear, let's say $P:3x_1+x_2-2x_3=0, \vec{x}=(-1,2,1),\vec{y}=(1,0,2)$, is it possible to determine which of $\vec{x},\vec{y}$ is closer to $P$ by only calculating the projections?

Comment: Is the given plane guaranteed to include the origin?  (If not, how are you defining your projection operators? since we can pick random, different points of the plane as the origin every time we project anything.)

Comment: Sure. The distance of $\vec x$ to the plane is $|\vec x-proj_P\vec x|$. So, you only have to compare $|\vec x-proj_P\vec x|$ and $|\vec y-proj_P\vec y|$ to see which one is closer to the plane.

Comment: @amsmath You're supposing $\vec x$ and $\vec y$ are parallel to the plane, right?

Comment: @Ripi2 Erm, no, I don't. This holds for all $\vec x$.

Comment: @amsmath Then I ask, for a not-parallel vector, which is its distance to a plane? The nearest point?

Comment: @Ripi2 $dist(\vec x,P) := \inf\{|\vec x-\vec p| : \vec P\in P\}$. And since $\vec p\mapsto |\vec x-\vec p| $ is continuous, there exists $\vec{p}_0\in P$ such that $dist(\vec x,P) = |\vec x-\vec{p}_0|$. And this $\vec{p}_0$ is exactly $proj_P\vec x$.

Comment: A different way of putting the above is that instead of examining projections onto the plane, you should examine projections onto the plane’s normal, since that’s how distance to the plane is measured, anwyay.

Answer (score 1):

Possible with only the projected vectors? No.

Consider the XY plane (z=0). And two vectors, (x,y,z1), (x,y,z2) (notice the same x,y). If you do an orthogonal projection to the XY plane, boths projections are the same, the z info is lost.

Generally speaking, all vectors in the same romboid defined by a vector and a direction of projection have the same projection.
For a perpespective projection, given a vector you can find another vector (with other size) contained in the plane of projection that has the same projection.